# Почему console выводит true?

Tags: javascript

Я хоть и новичок, но имею какие-то знания в JS ,и как мне известно, в данном коде:

```js
const stack = [];
console.log(!stack.length);
```

Должен выводиться **False** , типа **длина** массива **не равна 0**.

Ведь **!stack.length** - это отрицание его длины.

Тогда почему мне показывает **True**?

Comment: Если вы хотели «длина массива не равна 0», то так и надо писать `stack.length !== 0`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а зачем, какая практическая польза от части `!== 0`? Ведь стандартное свойство `length` js-массива всегда возвращает целое значение ≥ 0 (тип `number`); при этом, в языке нулевое значение всегда falsy, а ненулевое числовое значение всегда truthy => выходит что нет потребности в доп. операции сравнения и лишнем литерале `0`, достаточно типкаста значения к типу `boolean` проверкой `if (stack.length)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Число `0` в булевском смысле означает `false`. Его отрицание - `true`.

Comment: Благодарю, именно то, что я хотел узнать!